# Why is my code not outputting the first element of my vector, but outputs all the others?

Tags: c++, input, while-loop, stdvector

This code asks the user for input values, inserts the values into a vector and then outputs it, but for some reason does not show the first element, but shows all the others.

It might be something really stupid but I am relevantly new to learning c++ and just trying to refine over vectors but cant seem to get this one.

```
double x;
vector<double> l;
cout << "Enter a list of numbers: ";
cin >> x;
while (cin >> x) {
    l.push_back(x);
}
for (auto i = 0; i < l.size(); ++i) {
    cout << l[i] << " ";
}
```

Comment: Where do you read the first number? What are you doing with it? Please explain your code in great detail to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: try `std::cout << l.size();`. Your code does print all elements of the vector

Answer (score 1):

The first input for the variable `x` that occurs before the while loop

```
cin >> x;
while (cin >> x) {
```

is just ignored.

Remove this statement

```
cin >> x;
```

before the while loop.

Also pay attention to that in this for loop

```
for (auto i = 0; i < l.size(); ++i) {
    cout << l[i] << " ";
}
```

the variable `i` is defined as having the signed type `int`. However in general objects of the signed type `int` can be not large enough to represent sizes of vectors. So it would be better to use range based for loop like

```
for ( const auto &item : l ) {
    cout << item << " ";
}
```

Comment: Ah yes thats the one, how silly of me haha. Appreciate it!

Comment: @shadowz123123 you'll find you can eliminate huge numbers of silly mistakes by stepping through problem areas in the code with a debugger and watching what happens and comparing it to your expectations. When a line of code doesn't do exactly what you think it should do, you've probably found a bug, and since you know that the line was supposed to do, you should have a few good ideas about what you needed to do instead.